# Better "What Topics Can I ask about" Help page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

The Help centre page only says:

[What topics can I ask about here?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Ebooks Stack Exchange is for ebook publishers and readers.

Followed by a long message about other sites.

It is really sparse and not so informative. I actually thought I had clicked the wrong link, because most of the space is talking about if something is not on topic here, it might be somewhere else.

Even what it says is kind of unclear.

- Ebook publishers? Is that for software the creates ebooks? Companies that publish them?
  (Both are ontopic, as far as I can tell).
- Ebook readers? Is that people who read ebooks? or devices for it? Does that include software on a computer or only a handheld? (All of the above)

It could be alot better. Compare to [Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and [SoftwareRec.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Both of these have dot points and are quite informative. You know what you did wrong when something is closed for being off-topic (even if you didn't before.)

I guess it is just the default help page when the site is created. But other Beta sites have filled theirs in, so I guess we have the power to get the mods (or is it SE community managers for this) to fill it in for us.

What should our list of topics say?

Comment: This is a good point; thanks for bringing it up. I will try to clean this up.

Comment: P.S. Please propose any additions that come to your mind, as well -- you can put them in your question or in the answers, as either is appropriate here.

Comment: If I had any really solid solutions I would put them in an answer, but I am not really very deep in this SE, and am unsure exactly what is ontopic (or not) which is why i looking in the help